# Tortoise SVN - updating only SPECIFIC files in a list only

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

Good afternoon,
I have been asked by a colleague to see if something is possible within Tortoise SVN.

We have a local machine that needs only a specific list of .xls files updated in its checked out repo from the main svn server when you right click the main folder and choose update.

The files are located in several different folders, so it isn`t a case of simply deleting the contents of one folder and then calling update on that folder to restore the files with the most recent versions.

I was thinking if there was a way of writing a "list" of file paths that I could feed to Tortoise (no jokes about lettuce please ;)) and it would munch its way through item by item and update JUST those files?

Please help me Stack Overflow, you`re my only hope.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add the files/folders which you don't want to upload to the server to the `Ignore List`.

Steps: Right click on the file or folder that you don't want to upload and select `Tortoise SVN`->`Add to ignore list`. Repeat this for all  the files and folders.

### To update only a specific list of files from the main server/repo to a local machine

Steps: Select `TortoiseSVN`->`Update to Revision`->`Head Revion`. Also, `Update Depth`->`Working Copy`->`Choose items`-> This will open the folders in a tree structure where you can check ONLY the items that you want to update

Comment: Is the ignore list for the local machine only? It wont do anything to the main repo will it?

Comment: no, it is not for the local machine, it will update the ignore list to the main repo also. Ignore list is a property of the repo, which contains a list of all the files and folders that are allowed to exist in a user's local machine, but are not required to be uploaded to the repo. e.g. i want to keep a notes.txt in my local checkout copy, but i don't wan't to upload it, then i can add it to ignore list.

Comment: If you want, you can add these files to ignore list -> then commit -> then remove these files from the ignore list of the repo.

Comment: This is the opposite of what I need. I want only a specific list of files to be updated from the main server/repo to a local machine that is acting as an online data server for a project. Maybe the use of the term "server" was misleading, sorry. The local machine has a copy of the repo checked out - and I want to update a list of specific files on that machine whilst leaving everything else the same.

Comment: OK, then right-click on the specific files/folders which you want to update then select `TortoiseSVN`->`Update to Revision`->`Head Revision`. Repeat for all the files and folders which you want to update from the repo

Comment: I understand that but wondered if there was a way to automate the process of clicking each folder/file automatically if I have a series of file paths in a list

Comment: Yes, you can automate it. Select `TortoiseSVN`->`Update to Revision`->`Head Revion`. Also, `Update Depth`->`Working Copy`->`Choose items`-> This will open the folders in a tree structure where you can check ONLY the items that you want to update